# ASP.NET website as subfolder on PHP Nginx server

Tags: php, nginx, asp.net, mono

**My requirements:**
My website -> example.com - Runs Magento ecommerce platform built in PHP running under Nginx server *(currently Apache but very soon moving to Nginx)*
Another website -> example.com/abcd - abcd is currently another website that runs on ASP.NET
Another website -> example.com/xyz - xyz is currently another website that runs on ASP.NET

I want to co-exist PHP and ASP.NET website on 1 server with the ASP.NET websites running as a sub-folder.

**Background:**
1. The Magento website is an ecommerce website which cannot be re-built.
2. The ASP.NET is a corporate website that is investing money into the ecommerce website and it cannot be re-built either since they have many corporate websites and each which will run as sub-folder to the magento website.

**Research:**
Looked briefly at mono-project. However from my understanding you need to have separate domains and separate folders for the PHP and ASP.NET to exist on 1 server? Or is my understand wrong?

Can anyone over here provide me more information on whether this can be done. If so, what direction do I need to look into? As mentioned in the requirements, I cannot re-build (though can make minor changes) any of the corporate website into PHP as they have already been done and they are many of them. Also I know I can put a sub-domain http://abcd.example.com and make it point to another server with IIS but the corporates want that as the very last option.

My background is as a PHP developer so I have very little understanding of ASP.NET. So please be gentle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not real familiar with Mono, but looking at the nginx configuration for it ([Mono under nginx fastcgi)](http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI_Nginx), it should be possible to run both PHP-FPM and Mono through nginx using your described setup, using a config such as:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    // PHP
    location / {
        index          index.php;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000; // php server/port
    }

    // ASP.NET 1
    location /abcd {
        index          Default.aspx;
        fastcgi_index  Default.aspx;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   localhost:9001; // mono server/port
    }

    // ASP.NET 2
    location /xyx {
        index          Default.aspx;
        fastcgi_index  Default.aspx;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   localhost:9002; // other mono server/port
    }
}
```

You would then have to set different [root](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#root) for each location block.

Comment: I think this should be it. Will be implementing this next month so in case I run into any trouble will post back here.I don't think I have enough rep to up your answer! But thanks for pointing me in a particular direction :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not intimately familiar with how to run Mono in nginx and I don't want to spread FUD, but I'm not sure that setup is absolutely mature.

If you can, you might want to consider running everything in IIS on Windows Server. [IIS has excellent PHP support](http://php.iis.net/) and IIS has support for running separate in the subfolders in the way that you need. There's [more info here](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis#About7.0).

Comment: Magento is extremely resource intensive and has not been designed to work efficiently with IIS or Apache-Windows. It works ok for Apache but for millions of site users nginx can handle this best. So unfortunately I can't move all of them to IIS. If I can install IIS and Apache on 1 linux server & run main folder off Apache and the sub-folder off IIS then I'm ok too.